# Re-run specific job in Github Actions

Tags: github-actions

I see that it is possible to re-run github workflows from the UI, which is great. But is it also possible to re-run a specific job? let's say I have a pipeline with 2 jobs, one that builds my project and, the other one runs some tests, would it be possible to just re-run the tests without rebuilding the codebase?

Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: https://github.community/t/ability-to-rerun-just-a-single-job-in-a-workflow/17234

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible for now, you can only re-run full pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible since mid-March 2022 (2+ years later)

> ### [GitHub Actions: Re-run only failed or individual jobs](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-03-17-github-actions-re-run-only-failed-or-individual-jobs/)
>
> You can now re-run only failed jobs or an individual job in a GitHub Actions workflow run.
>
> If you have failing jobs in a workflow run, you’ll now see a new drop-down menu where you can choose “Re-run failed jobs” in addition to the existing “Re-run all jobs”.
>
> For a completed run, each job listed in the sidebar has a re-run icon when you hover over it. Jobs can also be re-run directly from the logs view.
>
> [image: re-reun this job icon]

Additionally, whe

Answer (score 0):

The [Apache NetBeans](http://netbeans.org) project had trouble re-running the individual workflow as well. Turned out the problem is in defining [multiple independent workflows in a single file](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/blob/9523af2ece6d2b59938db1580d573892d6e6f821/.github/workflows/main.yml).

By [splitting the single file into few](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/pull/3295) we can now re-run each workflow independently.